# shutdown ubuntu at specific time

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I am using **ubuntu server 14.04**, Now downloading in process and i am leaving office. I want to shut it down after 2 hours. please help me, how to do it.

This didn't work for me.

```
sudo shutdown -P 60
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what do **you** think `60` means in this context?

Answer (score 1):

From `man shutdown`:

```
The time string may either be in the format "hh:mm" for hour/minutes
specifying the time to execute the shutdown at, specified in 24h clock
format. Alternatively it may be in the syntax "+m" referring to the
specified number of minutes m from now.  "now" is an alias for "+0",
i.e. for triggering an immediate shutdown. If no time argument is
specified, "+1" is implied.
```

So it seems you're missing a `+` (and presumably you mean 120)

Answer (score 0):

You can use corn job to shutdown. The time and minutes you want to shutdown can be specified as below.

> sudo /etc/crontab:
>
> 30 21 * * * root shutdown -h now

Above entry will run shutdown command at 21:30.

> cron format:
>
> MM HH DD OO WW command MM: Minute, 0-59 HH: 24-hour hour DD: Day of
>   month OO: Month WW: Day of Week (Sunday is 0, Monday is 1) command:
>   Self-explanatory

Comment: Using a cron job in this context makes no sense. OP wanted to shut down the computer after 2 hours **now**. The `shutdown` command does that, `cron` will do that, but repeatedly!

Comment: To avoid cron job running repeatedly he can delete the crontab entry tomorrow.